# how to send data from controller to model with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm newbie with CI and i'm using CI v.2.2.1, i want send data from my controller to model but i have some trouble here. The error said my model is `undefined property`. here's my code :

Controller :
users.php

```
public function postUser(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $phone = $this->input->post('phone');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $level = $this->input->post('level');
    $status = $this->input->post('status');
    $this->load->model('model_crud');
    $query = $this->model_crud->insert('Users',$_POST);
    echo "$query";
}
```

Model :
model_crud.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_crud extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct(){
         parent::__construct();
    }

    public function insert($table,$data){
        $query = $this->db->insert($table,$data);
        return $query;
    }
}
```

is there any configuration to use model or my code is wrong?
can anyone help me ? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st thing, you're not providing enough information about the error.
Is the model loaded anywhere/anyhow? From the controller you load your model this way:

```
$this->load->model('model_crud');
```

Or you can preload it, by modifying your autolad.php config file

in postUser() - you're getting your post data, but don't really use it. Instead, you're passing the whole global $_POST, which may be dirty and unsafe. I'd recommend using CodeIgniter's XSS filtering when forming a data array from POST:

```
$data = array (
  'username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE); //TRUE identifies you're passing your data through XSS filter,
 //all other elements
);
```

finally:

```
$query = $this->model_crud->insert('Users',$data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by sending an array to your model with table columns name as key :

Controller :

```
$data = array(
      'username' => $this->input->post('username') ,
      'password ' => $this->input->post('password') ,
       ...
   );
// 'TABLE COLUMN NAME' => "VALUE"

$query = $this->model_crud->insert('Users',$data);
echo "$query";
```